# Appium - how to clear password field?

Tags: android, passwords, appium, textfield

I drive into the following problem that I am not able to clear a password field via the AppiumDriver (AndroidDriver). The 'clear()' command does not clear the field and then the new text will be set in front of the old one.

Strange is also the clear behavior of a simple text field (appium log):

1. Clearing text not successful. Attempting to clear by selecting all
   and deleting.
2. Clearing text not successful. Attempting to clear by
   sending delete keys.

After that the text was really cleared.

Back to the password field. Could be the problem that Appium is not able to see any charakters in the password field and then act as if the field is not filled?

I found some workaround here in other posts to mark the entire field and send a delete command, but AppiumDriver itself does not support the command sendKeyEvent(). So this will not work for me.

Used: Appium 1.4.8, appium java-client 3.0.0

Comment: Are you using an emulator? I am, and I've found that even when I manually interact with a password field, select all gets overridden.

Comment: Hi, kiminoa - no I am using a real device.

Comment: make sure you are calling right instance of driver. e.g. self.driver. For me self.driver.clear() works. You can try sending null characters first then send your password. e.g. element.send_keys("")

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into problems with clearing the password field, using Android Emulator + Appium + python. The workarounds mentioned elsewhere require a long-press or double-tap select-all, but the emulator happily overrode that by de-selecting, even when I tried doing it manually on the emulator.

Until there are a few more fixes available with both Appium and the emulator, I decided to take this drastic action during each `tearDown()` in my tests:

`self.driver.reset()`

Among other things, it clears the password field ;) If you have desired_capabilities 'noReset' set, comment that out for this, ahem, "workaround."

Comment: first of all, thanks for your answer - but it is not the workaround that I will prefer. Because I will not leave the view, but the reset() as far as I know will restart the app.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will clear the characters entered in text field.

```
        IOSElement Phone = driver.findElement(By.name(CUSTOMER_PHONE_NUMBER));
        String text1 = Phone.getText();
        int maxChars1 = text1.length();
        for(int i =0;i < maxChars1;i++) {
        Phone.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
        }
```